# Docker No such Image

Tags: azure-arc

I am working on setting up Azure Arc. The cluster diagnostics check fails as it is unable to get the image required which is "mcr.microsoft.com/azurearck8s/clusterdiagnosticchecks:v0.1.0"

*Local PC*: Docker pull works fine

*Ubuntu Server*: docker pull fails with: manifest verification failed for digest sha256:9a98a491a45e8a7317b93ff210e79822e5b430797b875e15a3fac30408d07d60

If I do a "docker image inspect mcr.microsoft.com/azurearck8s/clusterdiagnosticchecks:v0.1.0", I get "Error: No such image: mcr.microsoft.com/azurearck8s/clusterdiagnosticchecks:v0.1.0". This command works fine on my local PC.

However I tried downloading another image from the same Ubuntu server, mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.34.0-jammy and it downloaded fine.

Whats the issue with the "mcr.microsoft.com/azurearck8s/clusterdiagnosticchecks:v0.1.0" image?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to our firewall blocking some traffic.